# Multivariable Limit Prob

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}$$

I tried to prove that the limit DNE, but have not been able to because all the limits approaching (0,0) from different paths seem to go to the same number.

I have only learned techniques used to take limits of composite functions and plugging in x=0 and y=0 does not work either.

What is the step by step process to doing this question?

Comment: Morally speaking, this function is continuous at the origin and has a limit of zero there. This is because it can be extended to an continuous function by defining it as $f(x,y) = x$ for $y=0.$ This explains why you haven't been able to get it to go to anything but zero through creative choice of path. As written, the expression's limit is undefined because there is no neighborhood of the origin on which the expression is defined since the expression undefined whenever $y=0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{e^t - 1}t = 1$ we obtain:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{e^{xy}-1}{xy} \cdot x = \left(\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{e^{xy}-1}{xy}\right) \cdot \left(\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} x\right) = 1 \cdot 0 = 0$$